# Dymo - makes invalid Barcode, how to make exact value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dymo

I am using following Barcode printer to print exactly the value `000220200`, so that the scanner can get original value.

But when i print it out, and again scan with scanner it always getting : `5000220200` 10 in length instead of original `000220200`

```
  // used barcode <Type>Code128</Type>,tried all other types too
  var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);
  label.setObjectText("BARCODE", '000220200');
  label.print("DYMO LabelWriter 450"); // This is the NAME of the printer which i found
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any chance your barcode scanner or label document itself has a prefix set up causing the "5" to show up?  And is it always "5" being prefixed to the bar-code?

Comment: No there is no prefix value. Its not always "5" if i use other type of barcode from that drop-down list then instead of 5 it becomes 7 or 9 or so. So there is always one unknown value in begin.

Comment: Another thought I had was if you are using a trail version of the Dymo software?  I know other label software will do funky things with bar coded data until you purchase the software.  I have zero experience with Dymo software so I'm just taking shots in the dark here.  Do you get the same behavior when you print a able from within the dymo software?  Independent of printing it from code by automation?

Comment: With Dymo or without Dymo software, what-ever i print its adding that extra value.

Comment: I would confirm your are using a paid version of of the Dymo software.  If you are I would contact Dymo.  Another idea is to just strip off the first character when the barcode is scanned and it reaches your code.  If you are also handling the barcodes being scanned in that is.  Another alternative is switching to a different barcode software.  We use BarTender and it works really well for us.

Comment: I have the same sort of issue using Dymo's SDK, 2 labels 1 is 12mm one is 19mm 2 lines of difference in the XML those being sizes and the 12mm always comes off as invalid where the 19mm always works.... pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it Works. The problem was caused because i was using an invalid `<type></type>`

```
"Dear Dymo. Please fix exception errors, so that people buying your hardware can stop wasting time."
```